# Android - Custom TabHost Layout or Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-tabhost

I want to custom a layout as below : touch each Tab (NEWS/Video) will display content of each page.

I'm not sure if what exactly widget should be used : 2 Buttons or TabHost ?

Thank for helping.

[image: layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple method: setContentView but no feel good
another way: a custom tabhost with 2 RadioButtons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <ImageView
                android:background="@drawable/home01_23"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"></ImageView>
        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/main_radio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">  
            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text=""/>  
            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_2"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text=""/>  
        </RadioGroup>
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/main_radio"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Can you give me xml code ? I try use a TabHost with 2 TabSpecs but result is not exactly as this pic.

Comment: i have update it ,try it.

Comment: Thank you, JaveZh. In my case, i'm using 2 Buttons instead of RadioGroup which you used.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [library](https://github.com/yayaa/CustomTabsFragment), just not to deal with these stuff everytime... you may use it if you want.

Comment: I'll use your library to custom my layout. Thank for helping.